# Stuck without Qt4 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qt, 20.04, qt5

I just upgraded to Ubuntu Focal Fossa and found that the lack of Qt4 means it isnt possible to build [antimicro](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro)

I noticed [this post](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/issues/238#issuecomment-427962988) saying it would work with libqt4-dev, and I'm sure would as it compiled fine on earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Is there any way to install Qt4 on Focal Fossa?

With Qt5 it reaches 100%, but fails at 100% and gives lots of errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target antimicro_autogen
[  1%] Automatic MOC for target antimicro
[  1%] Built target antimicro_autogen
[  2%] Generating qrc_resources.cpp
[  2%] Generating ui_mainwindow.h
[  3%] Generating ui_axiseditdialog.h
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/axiseditdialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: '' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/axiseditdialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/axiseditdialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer_2' is not a valid widget.
[  4%] Generating ui_advancebuttondialog.h
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer_5' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: '' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer_6' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer_2' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: '' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: '' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: 'verticalSpacer_4' is not a valid widget.
/home/...../Desktop/antimicro-master/src/advancebuttondialog.ui: Warning: Z-order assignment: '' is not a valid widget.

[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/antimicro
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/antimicro.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `QtPrivate::MetaObjectForType<JoyButtonSlot*, void>::value()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9QtPrivate17MetaObjectForTypeIP13JoyButtonSlotvE5valueEv[_ZN9QtPrivate17MetaObjectForTypeIP13JoyButtonSlotvE5valueEv]+0xb): undefined reference to `JoyButtonSlot::staticMetaObject'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/antimicro.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `QtPrivate::MetaObjectForType<SetJoystick*, void>::value()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9QtPrivate17MetaObjectForTypeIP11SetJoystickvE5valueEv[_ZN9QtPrivate17MetaObjectForTypeIP11SetJoystickvE5valueEv]+0xb): undefined reference to `SetJoystick::staticMetaObject'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/antimicro.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `QtPrivate::MetaObjectForType<InputDevice*, void>::value()':

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/antimicro.dir/build.make:1804: bin/antimicro] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:165: CMakeFiles/antimicro.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Qt4 is EOL & unsupported upstream (2015 upstream though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) which is why it started to be removed entirely in 2019  in the *eoan* & *focal* cycles (refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295).  The app if maintained should have been ported to Qt5  (introduced 19-Dec-2012)

Comment: Somewhere else: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441709

Comment: And as suggested there, your best bet is to ask the developer or maintainer to move to `qt5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [simply available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=antimicro) with actual Qt5 dependency in the *universe* pocket for *focal*. Install with:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

Comment: Holy smokes ive been trying to build this for 2 days.... I never imagined it would be in the repos it never was before... thanks :)